# How to resolve the ambiguity between Boost::Program_Option which is used by two library I am using in my project?

Tags: c++, boost, linker, segmentation-fault, cucumber-cpp

I am using cucumber cpp and one more third party library in my code, but while running I am getting the segmentation fault, finally I found the root cause of this error this, this is failing because both library using `Boost::program_Option` it means two definition are there for same purpose.

Can you help me how to resolve this?

Comment: Link statically and/or compile against the same version of boost with the same compiler and flags (ABI)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sehe, You mean that, link both library statically to my code and compile it again, can you please elaborate your answer? , Because presently i am linking both libs statically only